# Do I have to protect bufferevent_write with mutex in a multithreaded server

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, libevent

`libevent` claims to be thread-safe, but I'm wondering if that means we don't need to run `bufferevent_write` protected by mutexes.

I'd like to run the function `bufferevent_write` of `libevent` in several different threads and they can be executed at the same time.

According to the documentation, `bufferevent_write` function adds data to a `bufferevent`’s output buffer, so it needs to protect the buffer, but I don't know whether it is already protected by a mutex or if I have to protect it manually?

Comment: Do you not care what order the data winds up in?

Comment: No, I don't care, the order has no importance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the source code of `libevent` it seems the mutexes are not included.
`bufferevent_write` calls `evbuffer_add`. I found the source code of this function here: http://transmission.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.75/event_8h_b652a2f82d23509713258a6e44697164.html#b652a2f82d23509713258a6e44697164
So I think I have to call these two functions:

```
void evbuffer_lock(struct evbuffer *buf);
void evbuffer_unlock(struct evbuffer *buf);
```